# Understanding recursion with small example

Tags: c++, recursion

Hi I have written small recursive method like this in cpp. I am trying to understand recursion

```
void print(int n)
{
    if(n==6)
        return;

    print(++n);
    cout<<n<<endl;
    //output is 6 5 4 3 2

}
void print(int n)
{
    if(n==6)
        return;

    print(n+1);
    cout<<n<<endl;
    //output is  5 4 3 2 1

}

void print(int n)
{
    if(n==6)
        return;

    print(n++);
    cout<<n<<endl;
    //programme crash

}
```

Could you please explain me what is happening internally?

Comment: Best way to learn is to use your debugger and step through the code.  That way you can see exactly how it is executed.

Comment: "Could you please explain me what is happening internally?" - it's *your* code, right? So says the opening sentence, anyway. So perhaps you should explain what *you* think is happening in each implementation by way of *your* intent in each case, and we can tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: think about what value is being passed when the argument to print() is ++n, (n+1), and n++.

Comment: Hint: when you're debugging for control and data flow, the first line of each function can or should be something that prints "ENTER", the function name, and the arguments (parameter values) in order.

Answer (score 2):

Function calls are placed on a stack. Think of this like a stack of plates. Any time "print(x)" is called in your code, it is another addition to this stack of plates. A function is removed from the stack when it gets to its closing curly bracket or when it hits a return statement.

I assume you're calling print(0) on these functions. As such print(0) is the first thing on the stack. Your last function crashes because it calls print(0) "forever" until it fails to have room for any more "plates." This is called infinite recursion and infinite recursion is rarely infinite due to the limitation of the stack.

As for the other functions, well, the "cout" statements are only called "after" functions are removed off the stack. Each of these methods keeps placing new things on the stack with one exception, the print(6) call. This is often called the base case and is the end of the recursive process. Because it begins a cascading removal of plates from the stacks which allows all the cout statements to occur (unlike the infinitely recursive case).

To understand how these codes differ, you must definitely make sure to understand the difference between n++, ++n and n+1 as well.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a problem in recursion as much as a problem in expression evaluation.  We have three routines that stop when n reaches 6; otherwise, they do some form of increment-and-recur, with different expressions.  After the recursive call, print the local value of **n** and return to the caller.

Note that each time you call **print**, you add a new local variable space to the run-time stack.  Each of these has its own copy of **n**: incrementing one doesn't change the others.

- **++n**  Increment the local value of **n** and call the function again.
- **n+1**  Don't change the local copy of **n**, but call the function again with the next-higher value.
- **++n**  Call the function again with the *current* value of **n**; as soon as you return, increment the local value of **n** and then print.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, it helps to try and illustrate the call sequence.

Imagine a sequence of function f1 thru f7 where f1 calls f2 which calls f3 and so on to f7. (because I started at 0, not 1)

f1 looks like:  (and the other are very similar)

```
void f1(int n)
{ 
   if(n==6)
      return;
   f2(++n); 
   std::cout<<n<<std::endl;
}
```

So the call sequence, initiated by f1(0), might be illustrated as:

```
f1(0)--v                : because f2 is called with ++n
       f2(1)--v         : because f3 is called with ++n etc.
              f3(2)--v
                     f4(3)--v
                            f5(4)--v
                                   f6(5)--v
                                          f7(6)
```

And every function call has a return:

```
                                          // no cout of 7
                                   return to f6(6)  
                                   cout<<... n is 6
                            return to f5(5)
                            cout<<... n is 5
                     return to f4(4)
                     cout<<... n is 4
              return to f3(3)
              cout<<... n is 3
       return to f2(2)
       cout<<... n is 2
return to f1(1)
cout<<... n is 1
```

Now, to move to using recursion, just replace the numbered f's with foo

```
void foo(int n)
{ 
   if(n==6)
      return;
   foo(++n); 
   std::cout<<n<<std::endl;
}
```

and the call sequence (initiated with foo(0)) might appear like

```
foo(0)--v               -- given 0, calls foo with 1
        foo(1)--v              -- give 1, calls foo with 2
                foo(2)--v             -- etc
                        foo(3)--v
                                foo(4)--v
                                        foo(5)--v
                                                foo(6) - return
```

I call the first part recursion ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

```
                                        return to foo(6)  (was 5)
                                        cout<<... n is 6
                                return to foo(5)  (was 4)
                                cout<<... n is 5
                        return to foo(4)  (was 3)
                        cout<<... n is 4
                return to foo(3)  (was 2)
                cout<<... n is 3
        return to foo(2)  (was 1)
        cout<<... n is 2
return to foo(1)  (was 0)
cout<<... n is 1
```

The second part, the returns of all these functions, the 'collapse' of this particular stack use, I sometimes note as  'decursion' (a new use of an old military term).  (The impact of the ++ operator makes alignment misleading.)

Because the cout is after the recursive call, (i.e. in the decursion) the output sequence is decreasing even though the input 'n' is increasing during recursion.

Thus, this particular sequence cout's 1 digit per line:

```
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Update - why did the last code snip crash?

The last code snip crashes because the post-increment happens after the recursive invocation.  So invoking foo(0), does invoke foo(n++), but this simply invokes foo(0) again, and then increments n (again).  The second and all subsequent foo() recursions each see the same value, 0, so the terminating condition (n==6) never occurs, and the stack overflows with the infinite function calls.